# how to increase line height between two option in multi select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to increase the line height between two option in multi select

HTML

```
<div>
    <select class="dk_multioptions_inner" tabindex="5" id="multiple" style="width: auto; visibility: visible; position: relative; font-weight:bold;" multiple="multiple">
        <option style="width: 150px;" value="Diploma degree">Diploma degree</option>
        <option value="Technical degree">Technical degree</option>
        <option  value="bachelor degree">Bachelor degree</option>
        <option value="Masters degree">Masters degree</option>
        <option value="Masters degree in technology">Masters degree in technology</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dk_multioptions_inner
{
    margin-left:-1px;
    margin-top:2px;
    color: #000000;
    max-height: 250px;
    border:1px solid #c997ba;
    background-color: #eeeeed;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f8, #dadad9);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f9f9f8), to(#dadad9));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f8, #dadad9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f8, #dadad9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f8, #dadad9);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;border-top-right-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;border-top-left-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/1jmcnu6r/)

How to increase the line height?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code that works exactly:

```
#multiple option{
   padding: 8px;
}
```

or

```
#multiple option{
   height: 30px;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: I posted the answer after verifying it. It's working. Please check it once.

Comment: am not seeing any difference

Comment: Not sure if this has got to do anything with browser versions. I am using Opera v23 and it doesn't work :( However it does work in Firefox.

Comment: @ViswanathD if possible give me fiddle link

Comment: @Harry Which browser you are using?

Comment: @ViswanathD he mentioned "I am using Opera v23"

Comment: @PandiyanCool In opeara there might be some problem as opera won't support many of the css properties.

Comment: but am using chrome and IE, the same thing happening there also

Comment: still same, have you checked in jsfiddle?

Comment: Same here.  I can use css to change the background-color of the options in a 'select', but changing the height, padding, line-height makes absolutely no difference in Chrome or IE9.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to style an element with varying styles from browser to browser. Not only that, but some browsers do not allow you to style the default dropdown options.

Your best option for styling drop downs, is to implement a custom select dropdown. There are several jQuery plugins that you could use. Unheap has a decent list of possible options: http://www.unheap.com/section/inputs-forms/selectboxes/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.dk_multioptions_inner').find('option').css("height", "20px");
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qre1pLet/

Comment: am not seeing any difference in result

Comment: @PandiyanCool, Check fiddle demo posted by me with your posted fiddle demo.

Comment: in fiddle its showing me the same result which i posted,(am using chrome to view fiddle)

Comment: am seeing some difference when i opened in firefox